# React - 500 Server Error when pressing a button

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, react-router

I'm working on a podcast app that has an e-commerce section for which I am following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CDtPMR5y0QU

I've been getting the following error from the network tab when I click the Place Order button:

> message: "Order validation failed: orderItems.0.product: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "1" (type string) at path "product", orderItems.0._id: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "1" (type string) at path "_id", orderItems.0.image: Path `image` is required., orderItems.1.image: Path `image` is required."

In the console, there is this error:

> POST http://localhost:3000/api/orders 500 (Internal Server Error)

I think this has to do with the images not showing up from the backend...it just has the <img> icon for when a photo does not show up. Could it be related to the folder structure? I've followed the code in the video exactly. This error came after implementing Video 28.

folder structure:

[image: folder-structure]

I added two "images" folders because they weren't showing up and I wanted to test them in the src and public folders. It didn't work for either.

Here is my code:

**BACKEND**

This is the data that is fed into the MongoDB models

```
const productData = {
  users: [
    {
      name: "example",
      email: "example@example.com",
      password: bcrypt.hashSync("123456"),
      isAdmin: true,
    },
    {
      name: "example",
      email: "example1@example.com",
      password: bcrypt.hashSync("123456"),
      isAdmin: false,
    },
  ],
  products: [
    {
      name: "LTBT Sweater",
      slug: "ltbt-sweater",
      price: 70,
      image: "/images/1.png",
      category: "Hoodies",
      countInStock: 10,
      description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit",
    },
    {
      name: "LTBT Keychain",
      slug: "ltbt-keychain",
      price: 50,
      image: "/images/1.png",
      category: "Accessories",
      countInStock: 9,
      description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit",
    },
    {
      name: "LTBT Sticker",
      slug: "ltbt-sticker",
      price: 20,
      image: "/images/1.png",
      category: "Stickers",
      countInStock: 17,
      description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit",
    },
  ],
};

export default productData;
```

This is the db model:

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const orderSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    orderItems: [
      {
        slug: { type: String, required: true },
        name: { type: String, required: true },
        quantity: { type: Number, required: true },
        image: { type: String, required: true },
        price: { type: Number, required: true },
        product: {
          type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: "Product",
          required: true,
        },
      },
    ],
    shippingAddress: {
      fullName: { type: String, required: true },
      address: { type: String, required: true },
      city: { type: String, required: true },
      postalCode: { type: String, required: true },
      country: { type: String, required: true },
    },
    paymentMethod: { type: String, required: true },
    paymentResult: {
      id: String,
      status: String,
      update_time: String,
      email_address: String,
    },
    itemsPrice: { type: Number, required: true },
    shippingPrice: { type: Number, required: true },
    taxPrice: { type: Number, required: true },
    totalPrice: { type: Number, required: true },
    user: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User", required: true },
    isPaid: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    paidAt: { type: Date },
    isDelivered: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    deliveredAt: { type: Date },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

const Order = mongoose.model("Order", orderSchema);
export default Order;
```

This is the orderRoutes file

```
import express from "express";
import Order from "../models/orderModel.js";
import expressAsyncHandler from "express-async-handler";
import { isAuth } from "../utils.js";

const orderRouter = express.Router();
orderRouter.post(
  "/",
  isAuth,
  expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const newOrder = new Order({
      orderItems: req.body.orderItems.map((x) => ({ ...x, product: x._id })),
      shippingAddress: req.body.shippingAddress,
      paymentMethod: req.body.paymentMethod,
      itemsPrice: req.body.itemsPrice,
      shippingPrice: req.body.shippingPrice,
      taxPrice: req.body.taxPrice,
      totalPrice: req.body.totalPrice,
      user: req.user._id,
    });

    const order = await newOrder.save();
    res.status(201).send({ message: "New Order Created", order });
  })
);
export default orderRouter;
```

This is the server.js file

```
import express from "express";
import cors from "cors";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import seedRouter from "./routes/seedRoutes.js";
import productRouter from "./routes/productRoutes.js";
import userRouter from "./routes/userRoutes.js";
import orderRouter from "./routes/orderRoutes.js";

dotenv.config();

mongoose
  .connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI)
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Connected to DB");
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err.message);
  });

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cors());

app.use("/api/seed", seedRouter);
app.use("/api/orders", orderRouter);
app.use("/api/store", productRouter);
app.use("/api/users", userRouter);

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  res.status(500).send({ message: err.message });
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`SERVER RUNNING ON PORT ${port}`);
});
```

**FRONTEND**

Here is the page that has the button (Place Order button)

```
import CheckoutSteps from "../components/CheckoutSteps";
import { Helmet } from "react-helmet-async";
import Row from "react-bootstrap/Row";
import Col from "react-bootstrap/Col";
import Card from "react-bootstrap/Card";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";
import ListGroup from "react-bootstrap/ListGroup";
import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useContext, useEffect, useReducer } from "react";
import { Store } from "../Store";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";
import { getError } from "../utils";
import axios from "axios";
import LoadingBox from "../components/LoadingBox";

//reducer for creating an order
const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "CREATE_REQUEST":
      return { ...state, loading: true };
    case "CREATE_SUCCESS":
      return { ...state, loading: false };
    case "CREATE_FAIL":
      return { ...state, loading: false };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default function PlaceOrder() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const { state, dispatch: ctxDispatch } = useContext(Store);
  const { cart, userInfo } = state;

  const [{ loading }, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, {
    loading: false,
  });

  //round to 2 decimal places
  const round = (num) => Math.round(num * 100 + Number.EPSILON) / 100;

  //calculate items price
  cart.itemsPrice = round(
    cart.cartItems.reduce((a, c) => a + c.quantity * c.price, 0)
  );

  //if total price is more than 100, make shipping price 15 otherwise it is 10
  cart.shippingPrice = cart.itemsPrice > 100 ? round(10) : round(15);

  //tax is 13%
  cart.taxPrice = round(0.13 * cart.itemsPrice);

  //total price
  cart.totalPrice = cart.itemsPrice + cart.shippingPrice + cart.taxPrice;

  const placeOrderHandler = async () => {
    try {
      dispatch({ type: "CREATE_REQUEST" });

      const { data } = await axios.post(
        "/api/orders",
        {
          orderItems: cart.cartItems,
          shippingAddress: cart.shippingAddress,
          paymentMethod: cart.paymentMethod,
          itemsPrice: cart.itemsPrice,
          shippingPrice: cart.shippingPrice,
          taxPrice: cart.taxPrice,
          totalPrice: cart.totalPrice,
        },
        {
          headers: {
            authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}`,
          },
        }
      );
      ctxDispatch({ type: "CART_CLEAR" });
      dispatch({ type: "CREATE_SUCCESS" });
      localStorage.removeItem("cartItems");
      navigate(`/order/${data.order._id}`);
    } catch (err) {
      dispatch({ type: "CREATE_FAIL" });
      toast.error(getError(err));
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!cart.paymentMethod) {
      navigate("/payment");
    }
  }, [cart, navigate]);

  return (
    <div>
      <CheckoutSteps step1 step2 step3 step4></CheckoutSteps>
      <Helmet>
        <title>LTBT | Preview Order</title>
      </Helmet>
      <h1 className="my-3">Preview Order</h1>
      <Row>
        <Col md={8}>
          <Card className="mb-3">
            <Card.Body>
              <Card.Title>Shipping</Card.Title>
              <Card.Text>
                <strong>Name:</strong> {cart.shippingAddress.fullName} <br />
                <strong>Address: </strong> {cart.shippingAddress.address},
                {cart.shippingAddress.city}, {cart.shippingAddress.postalCode},
                {cart.shippingAddress.country}
              </Card.Text>
              <Link to="/shipping">Edit</Link>
            </Card.Body>
          </Card>

          <Card className="mb-3">
            <Card.Body>
              <Card.Title>Payment</Card.Title>
              <Card.Text>
                <strong>Method:</strong> {cart.paymentMethod}
              </Card.Text>
              <Link to="/payment">Edit</Link>
            </Card.Body>
          </Card>

          <Card className="mb-3">
            <Card.Body>
              <Card.Title>Items</Card.Title>
              <ListGroup variant="flush">
                {cart.cartItems.map((item) => (
                  <ListGroup.Item key={item._id}>
                    <Row className="align-items-center">
                      <Col md={6}>
                        <img
                          src={item.image}
                          alt={item.name}
                          className="img-fluid rounded img-thumbnail"
                        ></img>{" "}
                        <Link to={`/store/${item.slug}`}>{item.name}</Link>
                      </Col>
                      <Col md={3}>
                        <span>{item.quantity}</span>
                      </Col>
                      <Col md={3}>$ {item.price}</Col>
                    </Row>
                  </ListGroup.Item>
                ))}
              </ListGroup>
              <Link to="/cart">Edit</Link>
            </Card.Body>
          </Card>
        </Col>
        <Col md={4}>
          <Card>
            <Card.Body>
              <Card.Title>Order Summary</Card.Title>
              <ListGroup variant="flush">
                <ListGroup.Item>
                  <Row>
                    <Col>Items</Col>
                    <Col>$ {cart.itemsPrice.toFixed(2)}</Col>
                  </Row>
                </ListGroup.Item>
                <ListGroup.Item>
                  <Row>
                    <Col>Shipping</Col>
                    <Col>$ {cart.shippingPrice.toFixed(2)}</Col>
                  </Row>
                </ListGroup.Item>
                <ListGroup.Item>
                  <Row>
                    <Col>Tax</Col>
                    <Col>$ {cart.taxPrice.toFixed(2)}</Col>
                  </Row>
                </ListGroup.Item>
                <ListGroup.Item>
                  <Row>
                    <Col>
                      <strong> Order Total</strong>
                    </Col>
                    <Col>
                      <strong>$ {cart.totalPrice.toFixed(2)}</strong>
                    </Col>
                  </Row>
                </ListGroup.Item>
                <ListGroup.Item>
                  <div className="d-grid">
                    <Button
                      type="button"
                      onClick={placeOrderHandler}
                      disabled={cart.cartItems.length === 0}
                    >
                      Place Order
                    </Button>
                  </div>
                  {loading && <LoadingBox></LoadingBox>}
                </ListGroup.Item>
              </ListGroup>
            </Card.Body>
          </Card>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Store.js file

```
import { createContext, useReducer } from "react";

export const Store = createContext();

//define initial state in cart based on local storage
const initialState = {
  //check if user exists
  userInfo: localStorage.getItem("userInfo")
    ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userInfo"))
    : null,

  cart: {
    //get shipping address, payment method and cart items based on user
    shippingAddress: localStorage.getItem("shippingAddress")
      ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("shippingAddress"))
      : {},
    paymentMethod: localStorage.getItem("paymentMethod")
      ? localStorage.getItem("paymentMethod")
      : "",
    cartItems: localStorage.getItem("cartItems")
      ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cartItems"))
      : [],
  },
};

//update state in cart
//instead of creating duplicate items of the same product, we increase the amount of the one product if button is pressed more than once

function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    //add items to cart
    case "CART_ADD_ITEM":
      const newItem = action.payload;
      const existItem = state.cart.cartItems.find(
        (item) => item._id === newItem._id
      );
      const cartItems = existItem
        ? state.cart.cartItems.map((item) =>
            item._id === existItem._id ? newItem : item
          )
        : [...state.cart.cartItems, newItem];
      localStorage.setItem("cartItems", JSON.stringify(cartItems));
      return { ...state, cart: { ...state.cart, cartItems } };
    //second case: remove item from cart
    case "CART_REMOVE_ITEM": {
      const cartItems = state.cart.cartItems.filter(
        (item) => item._id !== action.payload._id
      );
      localStorage.setItem("cartItems", JSON.stringify(cartItems));
      return { ...state, cart: { ...state.cart, cartItems } };
    }
    //clear cart
    case "CART_CLEAR":
      return { ...state, cart: { ...state.cart, cartItems: [] } };
    //update user info based on data from the backend
    case "USER_SIGNIN":
      return { ...state, userInfo: action.payload };
    //case where user is signed out
    case "USER_SIGNOUT":
      return {
        ...state,
        userInfo: null,
        cart: {
          cartItems: [],
          shippingAddress: {},
          paymentMethod: "",
        },
      };
    //update shipping address with data from payload
    case "SAVE_SHIPPING_ADDRESS":
      return {
        ...state,
        cart: { ...state.cart, shippingAddress: action.payload },
      };
    //save payment method
    case "SAVE_PAYMENT_METHOD":
      return {
        ...state,
        cart: { ...state.cart, paymentMethod: action.payload },
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export function StoreProvider(props) {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
  const value = { state, dispatch: dispatch };
  return <Store.Provider value={value}>{props.children}</Store.Provider>;
}
```

Edit: It works in Firefox, but not Chrome

Comment: one thing for sure is; error is from Backend, you should carefully debug in the API thats get called on onclick handler.. if you could post errors showing up in that controller then it would add some meaningful context

Comment: the error from the placeOrderHandler is `Order validation failed: orderItems.0.product: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "1" (type string) at path "product", orderItems.0._id: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "1" (type string) at path "_id"`
I just tried doing the same action in Firefox and it worked, I got a 201 status, but it won't work in Chrome

Comment: Server 500 error is backend, what debugging have you done? Are there any backend logs you can check?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to you set in the "orderRouter.post('/'...)"

`try {  //commands  } catch(e){  console.log(e); throw e  }`

Comment: thanks for your suggestion! i've implemented it within the expressSyncHandler function but i am still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

Could be that you are running the server on different port that your Front End?
In that case you are consuming from localhost:3000/api/... instead of localhost:5000/api/... I recommend that u test your apis with postman first.